# Adding subview during custom segue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this rather nice custom alert view for iOS 7+-like alert views.  [Here](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/01/transcending-uialertview-on-ios-7.html) is the source tutorial. The only issue I am having is the shadow subview that gets added does not appear to be working in iOS 7.  The root of that issue is in the downloaded sample project the shadow is added in the `UIPresentationController` subclass, and this does not exist in iOS 7, so I tried moving this into the animation block, but I am not seeing the view appear when the animation begins.

Here's where the shadow view gets added in the code called in the iOS 8 build:

```
-(void)presentationTransitionWillBegin
{
    [self decorateView:self.presentedView];

    UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
    UIView *v = vc.view;
    UIView *con = self.containerView;
    UIView *shadow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:con.bounds];
    shadow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.4];
    shadow.alpha = 0;

    [con insertSubview:shadow atIndex:0];

    shadow.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    [vc.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    {
        shadow.alpha = 1;
    }
                                              completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    {
        v.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed;
    }];
}
```

Here is where I try to do it in the iOS 7 code:

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController* vc1 = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* vc2 = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView* con = [transitionContext containerView];

    UIView* v1 = vc1.view;
    UIView* v2 = vc2.view;


        // presenting
        [con addSubview:v2];


        UIView *shadow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:con.bounds];
        shadow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.4];
        shadow.alpha = 0;

        [con insertSubview:shadow atIndex:0];

        shadow.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

        CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.6, 1.6);
        v2.transform = scale;
        if ( v1 != nil )
        {
            v2.center = v1.center;
        }
        v2.alpha = 0;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
         {
             shadow.alpha = 1;
             v2.alpha = 1;
             v2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             NSLog(@"v2 frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(v2.frame));
             [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
         }];
```

Here's a couple screenshots of the difference

iOS 7:

[image]

iOS 8:

[image]